# Linq to objects variation of contains

Tags: .net, linq-to-objects

All clear for

```
string[] names = { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" };

IEnumerable<string> query = names
    .Where   (n => n.Contains ("a"))
```

What actually I need

```
string[] providers = { "gmail", "yahoo", "hotmail" , "something" };
```

and determine with LINQ (  not necessarily  returning IEnumerable , bool will do  ) whether certain email address  somebody@**something**.com is from this provider list, i.e. element of array providers is case-insensitive substring of email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you be dealing with individual emails or a collection of em?

```
// individual
var email = ...;
var isValid = providers.Any(p => email.IndexOf(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1);

// collection
var emails = new[] { ... };
var validEmails = emails.Where(e => providers.Any(p => e.IndexOf(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1));
```

Comment: Are you sure about 2 arguments for contains. Gives me a syntax error in LinqPad 
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Mic: Sorry about that, I could have sworn there was an overload of `string.Contains()` that takes a comparer.  Anyhow, `IndexOf()` can be used for the same purpose.

Comment: M : I saw initial variant in other thread and somewhere else, that's why I had asked.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.

```
string[] providers = { "gmail", "yahoo", "hotmail", "something" };
string inputEmail1 = "test@gmail.com";
string inputEmail2 = "test@gmail2.com";
var query = from n in providers
            where inputEmail1.ToLower().Contains("@" + n + ".")
            select n;

Console.WriteLine(query.Count()); //For inputeEmail1,Print 1. For inputeEmail2, it will print 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check if the provided email address's *domain* exists in the list of domains. It will provide a bool.

```
string email = "me@hello.com";

string[] domains = new string[]{"hello", "goodbye"};

bool exists = new List<string>(domains).Exists(x => email.Conatains(string.Format(@"@{0}\.", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to do a case insensitive match of the text between the '@' and the first '.'.

So, here's my approach:

```
var providers = new []
    { "gmail", "yahoo", "hotmail", "something" };

var inputEmail = "test@gmail.com";

var match = inputEmail.Split('@')[1].Split('.')[0];
// You should probably expand this out to check for error in the input string.

Func<string, bool> isMatch =
    p => String.Compare(match, p, true) == 0;

var query =
    from p in providers
    where isMatch(p)
    select p;

var contains = query.Any();
```

I try to remove the detail of my query out to a `Func` to make the query sort of "extra simple".